# Finding whether or not a post containts carets ">" "<"

Tags: php

I'm using this:

```
strpos($_POST['content'],'>')
```

but it doesn't seem to be registering as true when I submit something with a ">"

Am I using it incorrectly? I also tried putting a backslash in front of the ">"

Comment: `strpos` (string position) will return the index of the first occurrence of given character/string in a `string` or `FALSE` if not found.

Comment: @Jite If also considered `TRUE` when an occurrence is found, because is not `0` (boolean `FALSE`)

Comment: It should return 0 for input: ">". Please check is it html encoded.

Comment: @CodrutzCodrutz What will `$result` be in this case: `$result = (strpos("string with < in", '<') === TRUE);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$pos1 = strpos($_POST['content'],'>');
$pos2 = strpos($_POST['content'],'<');

if( $pos1 !== false || $pos2 !== false )
{
    echo "TRUE";
    //POST CONTAINS < , >
}
else
{
    echo "FALSE";
     //POST DOES NOT CONTAINS < , >
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

strpos() will not return true, but the position of the first occurrence. This can be 0 which evaluates to false if you compare it with only ==.

You should use the ===/!== operators:

```
var_dump(strpos($_POST['content'], '>') !== false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use strstr() for this.

[strstr function PHP](https://www.php.net/strstr)

Comment: `strstr` is a 'heavier' function, and if you are just checking if there is an occurrence of a character in a string, `strpos` is cheaper and probably easier to understand/use.

Comment: @Jite What exactly do you mean by 'heavier'? More load time?

Comment: From the docs: `If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.`